# need help with geometry nodes to bend a mesh (waffle cone)

Tags: node-editor, geometry-nodes

I'm new to geometry nodes and tried to make an ice-cream cone. I managed to make a waffle base circle, but cant came up with any solution to bend the cone with geometry nodes. So currently it is bent with "Simple Deform" modifier, but I would like to achieve a similar effect with geometry nodes. I tried to manipulate "Set position" node, but I could only achieve a "tube" shape.

Also if you have any additional tips or comments about the model or ways to improve it, I will be happy to hear it. Thanks

[image: circle waffle base]

[image: Simple Deform modifier]

[image]